# MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_AVAILABLE error on windows

Tags: .net, ibm-mq

I have an ASP .NET core 3.1 application running on Windows server.

When I try to connect to MQ I get the error 'MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_AVAILABLE'.

Please find the code as below:

```
            string cipherSpec = "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256";
            string cipherSuite = "SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256";

            queueProperties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, strHostName);
            queueProperties.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, port);
            queueProperties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, strChannelName);
            queueProperties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);
            queueProperties.Add(MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY, "*USER");
            queueProperties.Add(MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SUITE_PROPERTY, cipherSuite);
            queueProperties.Add(MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SPEC_PROPERTY, cipherSpec);

            try
            {
                MQQueueManager _queueManager = new (queueManagerName, 
            queueProperties);
                _queueManager.Connect();
            }
            catch (MQException exp)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation(" Connection Fail " + exp.Message);
            }
```

Comment: did you check if there are any errors in the Queue Manager error logs

Comment: No I did not check because I do not have access to the Queue Manager logs.

Comment: You will need to have someone with access check the queue manager AMQERR01.LOG for any related errors.   I also would suggest you only set MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SPEC_PROPERTY, no need to set (MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SUITE_PROPERTY.

Comment: Okey I will try to access the logs and even I only set MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SPEC_PROPERTY the error continues.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?  what about logging?  I am having a difficult time getting the amqmdnetstd working in my .net app and I haven't figured out logging to find out why it can't connect

Comment: No I could not get it working and unfortunately no log message is displayed.